# When is the type (not category) of an expression used?

Tags: c++, expression, language-lawyer

I know every expression in c++ has a category (prvalue, xvalue, lvalue..) and a type which according to the standard draft, is never of reference type (may be cv qualified if not a prvalue)

> 5 If an expression initially has the type “reference to T” (8.3.2,
>   8.5.3), the type is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis. The expression designates the object or function denoted by the reference,
>   and the expression is an lvalue or an xvalue, depending on the
>   expression.
>
> 6 If a prvalue initially has the type “cv T,” where T is a
>   cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression
>   is adjusted to T prior to any further analysis.

Given that decltype has its own set of rules and the auto deduction has a different one as well, when does this “non-reference expression type” matter?

Comment: What do you mean exactly? What other parts of the language would be broken if the adjustment rule wasn't in place?

Comment: I don't understand either. It's just how the standard expresses the meaning of references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It matters in [unevaluated expressions](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.context#1):

`typeid`:

```
typeid(std::cout << 0) == typeid(std::ostream);
// true
```

`noexcept`:

```
template<class T> void f() noexcept(noexcept(T{}+T{}))
```

`sizeof` (even though [`sizeof` has a specific rule](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.sizeof#2), non contradicting with the rule for types of full expressions):

```
sizeof(std::cout << 0);
// the expression returns an std::ostream&, but its type is std::ostream
```

*etc.*

Comment: Sizeof may not be the best example... https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.sizeof#2

Comment: @StoryTeller in `sizeof(std::cout << 0)`, `sizeof` is *not* applied to a reference type.